# Base SAS: INTNX for identifying New and Existing Customers

Tags: date, sas

I'm trying to set two flags in a data set, one for New Customers and one for Existing.

New Customers = have an original_purchase_date in the previous month

Existing Customers = have an  original_purchase_date before previous month

And I want to pull in all activity  for the last 18 months as of the Last day in the previous month where the Last day in the previous month is

```
%let end='30Jun15'd;run;
```

This is what I have so far and I know this code is incorrect.

```
proc sql;
create table Cust as
select
*,
case when original_purchase_date between  intnx('MONTH', &end, -1)  and intnx('MONTH', &end) then 1  else 0 end as new,
case when original_purchase_date lt intnx('MONTH', &end, -1)   then 1 
else 0 end as Existing
from orders
where original_purchase_date between intnx('MONTH', &end, -1) and intnx('MONTH', &end, -1) -18;
quit;
```

Comment: %let end='30Jun2015'd;  (no 'run;' and better write yyyy for years)

Comment: What is that code doing/not doing that you know is incorrect?

Comment: In SAS, boolean expressions have a numerical result, equal to 1 if the expression is true and 0 if it is false, so you can just write  `original_purchase_date between  intnx('MONTH', &end, -1)  and intnx('MONTH', &end) as new` , without a `case`clause

Comment: The function intnx defaults to the first day of the period, so  `intnx('MONTH', &end, -1)` equals '01May15'd and `intnx('MONTH', &end)` equals '01Jun15'd. You actually need '01Jun15'd and '30Jul15'd

Comment: In your where clause, you specified a from date that is later than the to date. Moreover, subtracting a number from a date is actually subtracting days, not months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting your errors, I come to

```
select
    *,
    original_purchase_date between  intnx('MONTH', &end, 0)  and &end as new,
    original_purchase_date lt intnx('MONTH', &end, 0) as Existing
from orders
where original_purchase_date between intnx('MONTH', &end, -18) and &end;
```

`intnx('MONTH', &end, 0)` is the start of the month you specified in the `%let end = ...`, `intnx('MONTH', &end, -18)` is the start of the 18th month before it.

You can actually do better with

```
select
    *,
    original_purchase_date between  intnx('MONTH', Date(), -1, 'B')  and intnx('MONTH', Date(), -1, 'E') as new,
    original_purchase_date lt intnx('MONTH', Date(), -1, 'B') as Existing
from orders
where original_purchase_date between intnx('MONTH', Date(), -19, 'B') and intnx('MONTH', Date(), -1, 'E');
```

Here Date() is todays date (a date in the month after &end) and the fourth parameter of intnx specifies if you want the begin or the end of the month.